# Adjustment to jQuery resize of images to not make them appear large at first

Tags: jquery, image-resizing

Kind of an awkward title guys, sorry.

Anyway, I'm trying to resize my images with the following snippet of jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('img.FancyBox').each(function(){
$(this).width($(this).width() * 0.25);
});
});
```

Now, this works, but it would be really nice if I could find a way to specify the images to load 25% of their original size, rather than loading their original size, and scaling down.

It works, but it looks kind of odd.

Any sort of workaround would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you could set `.FancyBox` to `display: none;` in your CSS and then do:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.FancyBox').each(function(){
        $(this).width($(this).width() * 0.25);
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh!  Nice idea!  Good solution, as it appears as though it just took a little while to load.  I think I'll implement this, and just hard code the scaled down sized after a while xD. Thanks.